# canSendWriteWithoutResponse always returns false after some time

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am creating an app which connects with BLE device and continuously writes on one characteristic(withoutResponse write), in one session there can be around 150 write on an interval of 2-4 seconds, and after each session we are manually disconnecting the BLE device and before start of each session BLE device is reconnected, now when writing characteristics in second session and sessions after that, 'canSendWriteWithoutResponse' always returns false, also when i try to write to characteristic anyways it is not writing(ATT Send packet is not send) nor am I getting any error message. [I am using Packet Logger to keep an eye on Bluetooth packets].

If we disconnect to BLE device and reconnect it multiple times then it resolves the issue and it starts sending the packets again.

Software - iOS 15.2 |
Hardware - iPad 8th Gen |
BLE Board - Cypress CYBT-343026 EZ-BT WICED Bluetooth Module |
Xcode - 13.1 |

**CODE** -
I am only writing to the characteristic again after pervious write is successful, BLE device send an ack when it receives the write. So no race condition and stuff. Also I cannot write again unless previous write is successful, it is a business requirement. Also none of the packets are being lost[I am using Packet logger as well and logging the BLE device logs using serial connection.]

```
func sendBytesToDevice(_ bytes: [UInt8], characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    guard isReady else { return }
    
    if connectedPeripheral!.canSendWriteWithoutResponse{
        waiting = false
        print("Ready-",characteristic.uuid)
        let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes), count: bytes.count)
        connectedPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
    }else{
        print("Not Ready-",characteristic.uuid)
        waiting = true
        sendBytes = bytes
        sendCharacteristic = characteristic
    }
}

func peripheralIsReady(toSendWriteWithoutResponse peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Peripheral is ready now.")
    if waiting{
        waiting = false
        let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(sendBytes!), count: sendBytes!.count)
        connectedPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: sendCharacteristic!, type: .withoutResponse)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem?